# Microsoft.ReportViewer.*.dll's are not showing up in references (v11 or 12)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, rdlc

I have been working with RDLC reports using the ReportViewer.Common & ReportViewer.Web/WinForms dlls, version 10. The files produced by these dlls are a lot larger than those generated on a server instead of locally so I thought I would update the DLLs to v12. I downloaded and installed the 2012 redist:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=35747

However the dlls do not show up in the add references box - I can see version 8 and 10 in there but not 11 or 12 - all 4 versions exist in the GAC.

How can you reference these dlls properly? I am hesitant to change the registry or grab the dlls and reference them by browsing to them.. they both seem like hacks? Any ideas most welcome!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi please check [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/arvindsh/archive/2012/12/11/microsoft-report-viewer-2012-update-a-gotcha-to-be-aware-of.aspx) article as it explains why you may be seeing different versions.

The SQL Server Data Tools, including SSRS IDE, seem to be on a staggered release with Visual Studio in such a way that Visual Studio XX will be released and then at some point after the MSSQL and Data Tools support for Visual Studio XX will be released. That's why the SSRS Report Services IDE always looks one version behind.

Comment: Hi - thanks for that. I had seen that article actually and although I didn't really understand what he was driving at with most of it, I did install the package he recommended at the end. That installed the version 12 dlls into the GAC, but they are not available in the "Add References" part of VS2012

Comment: Did you install the Microsoft Report Viewer 2012 Runtime on your local machine and restart VS?

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply - I must have missed the notification. Yes - I did - and even now weeks later the installation they still don't appear in the references.. :(

Comment: You might be able to change the web.config by hand. If you have the files locally then it should compile and if you have the files on the server then it should run. Look for the Report Viewer entries in you apps web.config and change the version string manually and it should work. I think the version of visual studio you are using does not support what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that - I do do this from web apps too but in this case it is a WPF app. I am using VS2013 for what it is worth.