# Using ReportViewer in .NET app

Tags: c#, .net, reportviewer, rdlc

I'm trying to create simple app that support multiple .NET framework versions (2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5) on Windows XP, Vista, 7, 8.
All what the programm have to do - it is printing a rdlc report.

Currently i configured **supportedRuntime** to

1. v2.0.50727
2. v4.0
3. v4.0 sku=.NETFramework,Version=v4.5

What version of ReportViewer i must use?

Comment: There are multiple versions. This question may be useful --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27293005/microsoft-reportviewer-dlls-are-not-showing-up-in-references-v11-or-12/27299537#27299537

Comment: I know. 2005, 2008, 2010, 2012... I need one, that will run on each OS and .Net version.